# How to improve this query mysql and rails 5

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, mariadb

We have three tables `users`, `stores` and `store_customer_associations`, where a user can be a customer for many `stores`.

I've tried to place another index in primary key but without success (and other too).

(currently these are our indexes in each table)

```
mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM store_customer_associations;
+-------+------------+-------------------------------------+--------------+----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name                            | Seq_in_index | Column_name          | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+-------------------------------------+--------------+----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| users |          0 | PRIMARY                             |            1 | id                   | A         |     9386515 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| users |          0 | tmp_idx_users_id                    |            1 | id                   | A         |     9386515 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+-------------------------------------+--------------+----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM store_customer_associations;
+-----------------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                       | Non_unique | Key_name                                      | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| store_customer_associations |          0 | PRIMARY                                       |            1 | id          | A         |    51298761 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| store_customer_associations |          1 | index_store_customer_associations_on_store_id |            1 | store_id    | A         |       50096 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| store_customer_associations |          1 | index_store_customer_associations_on_user_id  |            1 | user_id     | A         |    25649380 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

We are using rails 5.1 (this is a big rails 4 legacy database).

Then we need to make this query fast:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM  `users`
    INNER JOIN  `store_customer_associations`
         ON `users`.`id` = `store_customer_associations`.`user_id`
    WHERE  `store_customer_associations`.`store_id` = STORE_ID;

+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|  1997632 |
+----------+
1 row in set (6.64 sec)


mysql> EXPLAIN     SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM  `users`
    INNER JOIN  `store_customer_associations`
         ON `users`.`id` = `store_customer_associations`.`user_id`
    WHERE  `store_customer_associations`.`store_id` = STORE_ID;

+------+-------------+-----------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table                       | type   | possible_keys                                                                              | key                                           | key_len | ref                             | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-----------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | store_customer_associations | ref    | index_store_customer_associations_on_store_id,index_store_customer_associations_on_user_id | index_store_customer_associations_on_store_id | 5       | const                             | 4401812 | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | users                       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,tmp_idx_users_id                                                                   | PRIMARY                                       | 4       | trustvox_production.store_customer_associations.user_id |       1 | Using index |
+------+-------------+-----------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
mysql> EXPLAIN     SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM  `users`
    INNER JOIN  `store_customer_associations`
         ON `users`.`id` = `store_customer_associations`.`user_id`
    WHERE  `store_customer_associations`.`store_id` = STORE_ID;

+------+-------------+-----------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table                       | type   | possible_keys                                                                                               | key                                           | key_len | ref                                              | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-----------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | store_customer_associations | ref    | index_store_customer_associations_on_store_id,index_store_customer_associations_on_user_id,user_id_store_id | index_store_customer_associations_on_store_id | 5       | const                                              | 4401812 | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | users                       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,tmp_idx_users_id                                                                                    | PRIMARY                                       | 4       | trustvox_production.store_customer_associations.user_id |       1 | Using index |
+------+-------------+-----------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
mysql>     SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM  users
    INNER JOIN  store_customer_associations
        FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN  (PRIMARY, user_id_store_id)
         ON users.id = store_customer_associations.user_id
    WHERE  store_customer_associations.store_id = STORE_ID;

+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|  1997632 |
+----------+
1 row in set (28.90 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN     SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM  users
    INNER JOIN  store_customer_associations
        FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN  (PRIMARY, user_id_store_id)
         ON users.id = store_customer_associations.user_id
    WHERE  store_customer_associations.store_id = STORE_ID;
+------+-------------+-----------------------------+-------+--------------------------+------------------+---------+------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table                       | type  | possible_keys            | key              | key_len | ref                                | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-----------------------------+-------+--------------------------+------------------+---------+------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | users                       | index | PRIMARY,tmp_idx_users_id | tmp_idx_users_id | 4       | NULL                               | 8675689 | Using index |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | store_customer_associations | ref   | user_id_store_id         | user_id_store_id | 10      | trustvox_production.users.id,const |       1 | Using index |
+------+-------------+-----------------------------+-------+--------------------------+------------------+---------+------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
mysql> EXPLAIN     SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM  users
    INNER JOIN  
        ( SELECT  *
            FROM  store_customer_associations
            WHERE  store_id = 75856
        ) sca  ON users.id = sca.user_id;

+------+-------------+-----------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table                       | type   | possible_keys                                                                                               | key                                           | key_len | ref                                              | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-----------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | store_customer_associations | ref    | index_store_customer_associations_on_store_id,index_store_customer_associations_on_user_id,user_id_store_id | index_store_customer_associations_on_store_id | 5       | const                                              | 4401812 | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | users                       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,tmp_idx_users_id                                                                                    | PRIMARY                                       | 4       | trustvox_production.store_customer_associations.user_id |       1 | Using index |
+------+-------------+-----------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
```

**UPDATE 4**

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE store_customer_associations DROP INDEX index_store_customer_associations_on_store_id;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE store_customer_associations DROP INDEX index_store_customer_associations_on_user_id;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> CREATE INDEX index_on_store_id_and_user_id ON store_customer_associations (store_id, user_id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (45.95 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> CREATE INDEX index_store_customer_associations_on_user_id ON store_customer_associations(user_id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (33.06 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> CREATE INDEX index_store_customer_associations_on_store_id ON store_customer_associations(store_id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (38.58 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM store_customer_associations;
+-----------------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                       | Non_unique | Key_name                                      | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| store_customer_associations |          0 | PRIMARY                                       |            1 | id          | A         |    10305620 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| store_customer_associations |          1 | index_on_store_id_and_user_id                 |            1 | store_id    | A         |        8244 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| store_customer_associations |          1 | index_on_store_id_and_user_id                 |            2 | user_id     | A         |    10305620 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| store_customer_associations |          1 | index_store_customer_associations_on_user_id  |            1 | user_id     | A         |    10305620 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| store_customer_associations |          1 | index_store_customer_associations_on_store_id |            1 | store_id    | A         |        6424 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: A simple count in store_associations returns: `52918798`

Comment: But how many rows have that `store_id`?

Comment: @RickJames only `4957` stores. And `9227084` users.

Comment: BTW, you could have done all 5 index changes in a single `ALTER TABLE`; it would have run significantly faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
store_customer_associations:  INDEX(store_id, user_id)  -- "covering"
```

`store_id` is first -- to handle the `WHERE`; `user_id` is added so that the only the index need by touched.

A tutorial that lets you discover the `INDEX` yourself:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: Indeed - I would actually prefer to have store_id, user_id as the primary key and get rid of the ID column, unless it's required by rails.
Even if it is you might still be able to use store_id, user_id as a primary key and create a unique key for ID

Comment: @Jesper - Good point.  If that pair is unique, replace id with it:  `PRIMARY KEY(store_id, user_id)`.  If `id` is required, it need be only `INDEX(id)`.  And toss your freshly made `INDEX(store_id)` since the composite key will be redundant.  But keep `INDEX(user_id)`.

Answer (score 2):

U need to make index for 2 parameters for store_curstometer_associations because in query index is not because where part.

```
create index user_id_store_id on store_customer_associations (user_id, store_id)
```

Should help u out

Example

```
mysql> show indexes from api_plexts;
+------------+------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name                               | Seq_in_index | Column_name        | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------+------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| api_plexts |          0 | PRIMARY                                |            1 | id                 | A         |      206318 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_plexts |          0 | index_api_plexts_on_guid               |            1 | guid               | A         |      215475 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_plexts |          1 | index_api_plexts_on_api_agent_id       |            1 | api_agent_id       | A         |        1565 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_plexts |          1 | index_api_plexts_on_from_api_portal_id |            1 | from_api_portal_id | A         |       11401 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_plexts |          1 | index_api_plexts_on_to_api_portal_id   |            1 | to_api_portal_id   | A         |        9566 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------+------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show indexes from api_portals;
+-------------+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name                             | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| api_portals |          0 | PRIMARY                              |            1 | id              | A         |       20530 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_portals |          0 | index_api_portals_on_guid            |            1 | guid            | A         |       19891 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_portals |          1 | index_api_portals_on_owner_agent_id  |            1 | owner_agent_id  | A         |         718 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_portals |          1 | index_api_portals_on_api_map_tile_id |            1 | api_map_tile_id | A         |        5480 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
explain select count(*) from api_portals ap JOIN api_plexts al FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (PRIMARY) on ap.id = al.from_api_portal_id  where al.api_agent_id = 2\G;


mysql> show indexes from api_plexts;
+------------+------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name                               | Seq_in_index | Column_name        | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------+------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| api_plexts |          0 | PRIMARY                                |            1 | id                 | A         |      206318 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_plexts |          0 | index_api_plexts_on_guid               |            1 | guid               | A         |      215475 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_plexts |          1 | index_api_plexts_on_api_agent_id       |            1 | api_agent_id       | A         |        1565 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_plexts |          1 | index_api_plexts_on_from_api_portal_id |            1 | from_api_portal_id | A         |       11401 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_plexts |          1 | index_api_plexts_on_to_api_portal_id   |            1 | to_api_portal_id   | A         |        9566 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------+------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show indexes from api_portals;
+-------------+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name                             | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| api_portals |          0 | PRIMARY                              |            1 | id              | A         |       20530 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_portals |          0 | index_api_portals_on_guid            |            1 | guid            | A         |       19891 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_portals |          1 | index_api_portals_on_owner_agent_id  |            1 | owner_agent_id  | A         |         718 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_portals |          1 | index_api_portals_on_api_map_tile_id |            1 | api_map_tile_id | A         |        5480 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+

mysql> explain select count(*) from api_portals ap JOIN api_plexts al on ap.id = al.from_api_portal_id where al.api_agent_id = 2;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                           | key                              | key_len | ref                           | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | al    | NULL       | ref    | index_api_plexts_on_api_agent_id,index_api_plexts_on_from_api_portal_id | index_api_plexts_on_api_agent_id | 5       | const                         |  271 |   100.00 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ap    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                 | PRIMARY                          | 8       | ingress.al.from_api_portal_id |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+

this is exactly your case U can see using where
mysql> create index testime on api_plexts (api_agent_id, from_api_portal_id);                                                                                                                               Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.71 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show indexes from api_plexts;
+------------+------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name                               | Seq_in_index | Column_name        | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------+------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| api_plexts |          0 | PRIMARY                                |            1 | id                 | A         |      200644 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_plexts |          0 | index_api_plexts_on_guid               |            1 | guid               | A         |      209549 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_plexts |          1 | index_api_plexts_on_api_agent_id       |            1 | api_agent_id       | A         |        1522 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_plexts |          1 | index_api_plexts_on_from_api_portal_id |            1 | from_api_portal_id | A         |       11087 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_plexts |          1 | index_api_plexts_on_to_api_portal_id   |            1 | to_api_portal_id   | A         |        9303 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_plexts |          1 | testime                                |            1 | api_agent_id       | A         |        1817 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| api_plexts |          1 | testime                                |            2 | from_api_portal_id | A         |       52277 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------+------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

VOILA!!!

mysql> explain select count(*) from api_portals ap JOIN api_plexts al on ap.id = al.from_api_portal_id where al.api_agent_id = 2\G;                            *************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: al
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: index_api_plexts_on_api_agent_id,index_api_plexts_on_from_api_portal_id,testime
          key: testime
      key_len: 5
          ref: const
         rows: 271
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: ap
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: ingress.al.from_api_portal_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: For the first time I've run took 58 secs. Then the next calls continue the same 6, 7 secs. Unfortunately does not worked for me :/

Comment: did u add create index user_id_store_id on store_customer_associations (user_id, store_id)
And what explains count shows now?

Comment: Also why u need to join user table to get counts .. just to verify that user exists for store_customer_associations ?

Comment: This query is autogenerated by rails.

Comment: Check out the UPDATE 1 @Imre Raudsepp ;)

Comment: try
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` INNER JOIN `store_customer_associations` FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (PRIMARY,user_id_store_id) ON `users`.`id` = `store_customer_associations`.`user_id` WHERE `store_customer_associations`.`store_id` = STORE_ID;

Comment: EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM store_customer_associations WHERE store_id = STORE_ID) sca ON users.id = sca.user_id what this does say